# Casting between integer formats with Python ctypes

Tags: python, casting, ctypes

How can I use the ctypes "cast" function to cast one integer format to another, to obtain the same effect as in C:

```
int var1 = 1;
unsigned int var2 = (unsigned int)var1;
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> cast((c_int*1)(1), POINTER(c_uint)).contents
c_uint(1L)
>>> cast((c_int*1)(-1), POINTER(c_uint)).contents
c_uint(4294967295L)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than using cast() is using .value on the variable:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> x=c_int(-1)
>>> y=c_uint(x.value)
>>> print x,y
c_long(-1) c_ulong(4294967295L)
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer to Structure typecasting

```
from ctypes import *

class head(Structure):
    _fields_=[
              ('x',c_ubyte),
              ('y',c_ubyte)
             ]

x = c_uint(0x3234)
px= cast(pointer(x),POINTER(head))

print(px[0].x)
print(px[0].y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions

An example is `ctypes.cast((ctype.c_byte*4)(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have read the documentation, but I am still unclear as to how to perform the conversion mentioned in my post.